# SQLException: No suitable driver found for connectionStr

Tags: java, sql-server, testng, spring-jdbc

I tried connect to MS SQL server in testng Java project using Spring JDBCtemplate. 
I have placed sqljdbc42 in java build path. I"m using Java Se 1.8. I"m using window authentication when connection using SSMS. Below is my code:

```
try {  
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instance=KUL11N0099313\\SQLEXPRESS\\test");
    dataSource.setUsername("wims\\kwong");
    dataSource.setPassword("");
} catch (Exception ex) {
    LogManager.logger.log(Level.INFO, "Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Error Message from debug variables:

> CannotGetJdbcConnectionException:
>   Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   java.sql.SQLException:  No suitable driver found for 
>   jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;instance=KUL11N0099313\SQLEXPRESS\test

Please help. What is the cause of the problem? Is it connection string error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: an advice that is not a solution...maybe.  If you don't need any particular strange stuff from microsoft, http://jtds.sourceforge.net/ is a really good open source jdbc driver for microsoft. easy to configure and you can grabbit from maven/gradle without problems

Comment: jtds may not be my solution because i need to use newer version of MS SQL server.

Comment: @rick, jtds hasn't been updated to support Microsoft SQL Server data types introduced after SQL Server 2000. It also doesn't support table-valued parameters and bulk copy.

Answer (score 0):

According to the driver [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-2017), the connection string should be of the general form

`jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;property=value[;property=value]]`

So you might have to remove `microsoft` from your connection string.

Comment: I got one exception: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select * from dbo.theLogin tl;]; The index 1 is out of range.